# How to get access token from outlook api to asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

I am working on simple web application where I need to get access token from outlook API in my app to use employee name and its image.I have written code and and able to login through outlook but my access token is coming as null.Please find my code below:

```
public void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

    // End the operation
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
    Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
    string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
    access_token = responseString;
    // Close the stream object
    streamResponse.Close();
    streamRead.Close();

    // Release the HttpWebResponse
    response.Close();
    allDone.Set();
}
```

Comment: do you use `UserAgent` for your request?

Comment: No i dont use UserAgent

Comment: you have to add some headers like `UserAgent` or `Content-Type` or `Connection` and most important of them is cookies which responded to first get request. try to add these headers and try to change these headers with each other to get desire response.

Answer (score 1):

HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("some url");

request.Method = "POST";

request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 7.1; Trident/5.0)";

request.Accept = "/";

request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

doc.Save(request.GetRequestStream());

HttpWebResponse resp = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

Hope it helps